# Running sh as part of assembling android project on git action yml

Tags: android, github, cmake, yaml, continuous-integration

In order for my project to run i need to run a script that building my Cmake folder, so when i do Ci with git action i need to run this :

```
cd app/src/main/cpp
```

than

```
sh build_cmake.sh
```

I have something like that :

```
  - name: Check out repository code
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: List files in the repository
    run: |
      ls ${{ github.workspace }}
  - name: Setting up Cmake
    run: |
      cd app/src/main/cpp  - name: Setting up Cmake
  - name: running script
    run: |
      sh build_cmake.sh
```

obviously that is not working,
how my goal can be achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put both commands in one `run`:

```
  - name: running script
    run: |
      cd app/src/main/cpp
      sh build_cmake.sh
```

Another way to solve is to use `working-directory` (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun) property:

```
  - name: running script
    working-directory: app/src/main/cpp
    run: |
      sh build_cmake.sh
```